# Explode dataframe based on daterange

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe `df` like so:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    StartDate   EndDate     Qty
24HR    A1      B1      1/5/2020    2/28/2020   4.2
asd     A2      B2      5/5/2020    7/15/2020   35
```

I want to repeat each row of the dataframe based on number of months between `StartDate` and `EndDate` to get something of the following sort:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    StartDate   EndDate    Qty
24HR    A1      B1      1/5/2020    1/31/2020   4.2
24HR    A1      B1      2/1/2020    2/28/2020   4.2
asd     A2      B2      5/5/2020    5/31/2020   35
asd     A2      B2      6/1/2020    6/30/2020   35
asd     A2      B2      7/1/2020    7/15/2020   35
```

I can use something of this sort but it is working out logically:

```
df.StartDate = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x['StartDate'], end=x['EndDate'], freq='MS'), axis=1)
df = df.explode('StartDate')
```

I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62178394/resample-a-start-end-employee-holiday-table-correctly) should help

Comment: What is your problem then, you have solution ..

Comment: It doesn't give the desired answer. :). Selecting any freq deviates from the StartDate or EndDate requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do the quick fix

```
df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x['StartDate'], end=x['EndDate'], freq='D'), axis=1)
df=df.explode('Date')
df['Month']=df.Date.dt.strftime('%y-%m')
df=df.groupby(['Col1','Col2','Col3','Qty','Month']).Date.agg(['first','last']).reset_index()
df
   Col1 Col2 Col3   Qty  Month      first       last
0  24HR   A1   B1   4.2  20-01 2020-01-05 2020-01-31
1  24HR   A1   B1   4.2  20-02 2020-02-01 2020-02-28
2   asd   A2   B2  35.0  20-05 2020-05-05 2020-05-31
3   asd   A2   B2  35.0  20-06 2020-06-01 2020-06-30
4   asd   A2   B2  35.0  20-07 2020-07-01 2020-07-15
```

Comment: ".Date.agg(['first','last'])" is genius. Never thought of that.